# Location for 3rd party component that will be used during the build (gradle)

Tags: gradle, directory-structure

We have one project that reuses 3rd party war (it's `shindig-server-2.0.2.war` if anyone asks:). This war currently sits in project root and the current ant tasks unzips it into some `temp` folder, performs several changes (like applying fixes, modifies the `web.xml` etc.) and finally build the war from our sources and the war content. This 3rd party is checked into the source repo.

We are migrating to gradle. Where should we put this file in Maven directory structure?

It does not look it belongs to `/src/main/resources` as it is not packed withing the artifcat; also, imho it does not belong to `/src`, too. Should we have a `/lib/resources` folder in root where we could store such files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Maven directory structure defines a place for local dependencies, and since this is a Gradle build, it doesn't really matter either. I wouldn't put it under `src`, but `lib` sounds fine.